# Пересылка сообщений в телеграмм бота из созданного телеграмм канала

Tags: python, telegram

Суть бота заключается в том, что если пользователь выбирает тему, то через определённый промежуток времени бот будет присылать ему сообщения из телеграмм канала (все нужные телеграмм каналы уже созданы) в чат с ботом. Проблема заключается в том, что пересылка сообщений из канала в чат не работает.

```
# pip install pytelegrambotapi

import telebot
from telebot import types
# import config
import time
# from telethon import TelegramClient, events
# # from aiogram import Bot, types

#
# from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
# from aiogram.utils import executor
# import asyncio
# # from telethon import TelegramClient, events
# # from collections import deque
# # from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop


bot = telebot.TeleBot('5321447421:AAGQ5BuFSTFdHSaDSmhaSOgOX8AXiAeMAWU')

name = ''
theme = ''
mon = 0
chatID = ''



@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, меня зовут NewsBot, как я могу к тебе обращаться?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, hello)


def hello(message):
    global name
    global chatID
    name = message.text
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Искусство")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Кино")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Садоводство")
    btn4 = types.KeyboardButton("Наука и техника")
    btn5 = types.KeyboardButton("Спорт")
    btn6 = types.KeyboardButton("Инвестиции")
    btn7 = types.KeyboardButton("Автомобили")
    btn8 = types.KeyboardButton("Кулинария")
    btn9 = types.KeyboardButton("Мода")
    btn10 = types.KeyboardButton("Все темы сразу")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn10)
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Отлично, "+name+". Какая тема тебе больше всего интересна?".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)


    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, buy)
    return name


def buy(message):
    global theme
    global chatID
    theme = message.text
    if theme == "Искусство":
        chatID = '-1001641835381'
    elif theme == "Кино":
        chatID = ''
    elif theme == "Садоводство":
        chatID = ''
    elif theme == "Наука и техника":
        chatID = ''
    elif theme == "Спорт":
        chatID = ''
    elif theme == "Инвестиции":
        chatID = ''
    elif theme == "Автомобили":
        chatID = ''
    elif theme == "Кулинария":
        chatID = ''
    elif theme == "Мода":
        chatID = ''
    elif theme == "Все темы сразу":
        chatID = ''
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="На такую комманду я не запрограммирован..")
        return theme
    mis = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хороший выбор, мне тоже нравится тема '+theme+'! Скажи пожалуйста, раз в сколько минут ты хочешь получать сообщения по выбранной теме??')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mis, tim)
    return theme


def tim(message):
    global mon
    while mon == 0:
        try:
            mon = int(message.text)
        except Exception:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Цифрами, пожалуйста')
    mon = int(message.text)
    mon = mon * 60
    mins = mon
    if mon == 60:
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Замечательно, ты будешь получать уведомления раз в минуту.')
    elif mon == 120:
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Замечательно, ты будешь получать уведомления раз в '+mon / 60+' минуты.')
    elif mon == 180:
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Замечательно, ты будешь получать уведомления раз в '+mon / 60+' минуты.')
    elif mon == 240:
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Замечательно, ты будешь получать уведомления раз в '+mon / 60+' минуты.')
    else:
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Замечательно, ты будешь получать уведомления раз в '+mon / 60+' минут.')
    a = 0
    while a == 0:
        while mins > 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            mins = mins - 1
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, answers)

        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'document', 'audio', 'video'])
        def all_media_messages(message):
            bot.forward_message(chatID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)

        # bot.forward_message(
        #     chat_id=msg.chat.id,  # chat_id чата в которое необходимо переслать сообщение
        #     from_chat_id=msg.chat.id,  # chat_id из которого необходимо переслать сообщение
        #     message_id=msg.message_id  # message_id которое необходимо переслать
        # )

        # @bot.on(events.NewMessage(chatID))
        # async def main(event):
        #     await bot.forward_messages(chatID, event.message)

        mins = mon

def answers(message, res = False):
    answer = message.text
    if answer == "/stop":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хорошо, до скорых встреч! но помни, чтобы снова начать работу напиши /start.')
    elif answer == "/theme":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Давай!")
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Я уже передумал)))")
        markup.add(item1)
        markup.add(item2)
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ну если ты так хочешь изменить тему, то давай сделаем это!')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, handle_text)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши:/n/theme, чтобы изменить тему/n/stop, чтобы закончить работу')


def handle_text(message):
    go = message.text
    if go == 'Давай!':
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, hello)
    else:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Конечно не против!")
        markup.add(item1)
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тогда, если ты не против, я продолжу свою работу!')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, but)


def but(message):
    mis = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напомни мне пожалуйста, раз в сколько минут ты хочешь получать уведомления по выбранной теме?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mis, tim)


# @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def get_text_messages(message):
    bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'audio'])
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, чтобы начать работу напиши /start.')
    elif message.text == "Спасибо":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Обращайтесь!")
    elif message.text == "спасибо":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Всегда пожалуйста")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши "Привет"')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help, чтобы узнать о моих возможностях.")


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Могли бы вы указать конкретную строчку кода которая не работает, сейчас я думаю что ошибка либо с в том что вы используете message_handler() вместо channel_post_handler(), либо неправильно передаёте параметры в bot.forward_message()